# Looking for the WooCommerce Documentation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WooCommerce, I am looking for a place where all the documentation for the available functions in WooCommerce are. I have looked on http://docs.woothemes.com/ but it just seems to contain a few snippets which aren't helpful to me.

I was trying to do something as simple as listing the product categories but have no idea where to start. It does not seem to be as obvious as when I need to find Wordpress functions.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the shortcode? http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/ Use the product categories shortcode...

Comment: @msbodetti I could do this, if I knew how to customise the HTML output as I want to add some extra information (eg descriptions ect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation for WooCommerce can be found here: http://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with product categories? Do you want to list them for a specific product or display all product categories available?

You may want to take a look at the code contained with content-product_cat.php which can be found in your woocommerce/templates directory. If you're editing the template, be sure to move this file to your [theme directory for template overriding](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).